# Read uncommitted isolation level doesn't allow to read entries

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactions, locking

I need to read dirty entries in Sql server but I don't understand why I can't. Hope you will help.
I have two tabs in management studio with following code
Tab 1:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE decision.tRequests
    SET IsComplete = 0

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:25.000'        
COMMIT TRAN
```

Tab 2:

```
SELECT * FROM decision.tRequests
```

When I run tab1 and then tab2 I can see that the query from tab2 takes more than 25 seconds to complete. When run script form tab2 without tab1 it take 0 seconds to complete.
Why even if I have `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` are the entries locked?

Comment: Stop and think of what you are trying to do here. You're updating the whole table in your first transaction and while it's open you're trying to read from that table with read commited (default) isolation level in another transaction. Either use dirty reads or snapshot isolation in your reading transaction to avoid wait-ups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in Tab2 not Tab1.

Tab2 will still be running under the default `READ COMMITTED` level.

Answer (score 1):

in Tab 2

```
SELECT * FROM decision.tRequests with (nolock)
```